# Delete entire blob information through BlobInfo (blob overwrite purpose)

Tags: google-app-engine

I realize my entire blob information, is not being deleted properly, if I try to delete it through BlobInfo. (I want to perform blob overwrite) My code is as follow :

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

class Human(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    checksum = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    version = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    content = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
```

---

```
def upload(email, checksum, version, content):
    # Create the file
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=email)

    # Open the file and write to it
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(content)

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)

    human = model.Human(key_name=email, email=email, checksum=checksum, version=version, content=blob_key)

    # Remove previous blob referenced by this human.
    query = model.Human.all()
    query.filter('email =', email)
    # q.content is blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
    for q in query:
        q.content.delete()

    human.put()
```

However, after I had write the blob several time, based on same human, here is how my database looks like. I had uploaded for 3 times. I am only expecting to observe only one row. However, I realize there are 3 rows in `__BlobFileIndex__`. `Human` and `__BlobInfo__` just look fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I perform proper delete based on BlobInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform a blob overwrite. Once finalized, a blob is immutable until deleted.

Test that to convince yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the answer. I blobstore.delete(blobkey) before I create a new blob and replace the reference, and exactly like presented in the question, the __BlobFileIndex__ still contains entries for the previous (and deleted) blobs. So blobstore.delete() doesn't seem to delete this blob file index. Am I missing something? Edit: I just tested to only deleting the blob and everything is gone except for the entry in BlobFileIndex. Should this index entry be deleted using another function?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
blobstore.delete( '<blobstore_key>' )
```

Comment: I change to blobstore.delete([q.content]). It doesn't work. It turns out that, __BlobInfo__ is having multiple entries too.

Comment: each time your script executes it creates a new blobstore entry and overwrites your "Human" entity. So, for what ever reason if you fail to delete the previous blobsore entry before overwriting the "Human" entity, you will loose the reference to old blobstore and will result in multiple blobstore rows.

Comment: try, blobstore.delete( q.content.key() )

Comment: Won't work. `__BlobFileIndex__` still contain multiple list. But `__BlobInfo__` looks fine.